# Dockerize a multi maven project (not multi-module)

Tags: maven, docker

In my maven application i have multiple projects:

- Core
- Application 1
- Application 2

`Application 1` and `Application 2` are two projects that uses the `core` (for example, those application are built for two different customers)

In order to Dockerize all of them, the simplest way would be to create a multi-module project, but the downside is that i have all inside a single project (core + Application 1 + Application 2).

I would like to have the core separated from them.

The main problem with this configuration is that the `core` project need to built before the other two, and `App 1` and `App 2` use this as maven dependency:

`App 1`

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>it.myorg</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

If i try to dockerize the `App 1` its fail when i package it, because inside the docker container core-project 1.12.0-SNAPSHOT do not exists.

I was thinking to setup a "local maven repo", pushing the core there and `App 1` will "pull" the jar from the repo and not from `.m2` folder, but i dont like this soulution.

I can provide more information, sorry if i dont provide examples, but my paper is white right now :(

**Folder structure**

```
+- Core
--- pom.xml
--- src

+- Application1
--- pom.xml
--- src
```

The solution i'm trying to do now is create a Dockerfile for core project (FROM maven:latest), building the image with a tag and in Dockerfile of App1 use this image (so, creating a multi stage build but in two separate moments).

The best would be

```
FROM maven:latest as core-builder
## build the core

FROM maven:latest
## Copy jar from builder
```

Because the project are in separate folder, i cant build the core in this way. I need to build del core BEFORE (running docker build -t) and later copy from them.

**UPDATE**

After the correct answer from @mihai i'm asking if its possible a structure like this:

```
-- myapp-docker
  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
-- core-app
-- application_1
```

Having Dockerfile at the same level of `core-app` and `application_1` its totally fine and 100% working. The only "problem" is that i should put all the projects in the same repo.

Comment: You should use multi-stage builds for this: one for app1 and one for app2. In both cases the first stage is to build Core. in the second stage you copy the .m2 folder and do the build. So you need 2 Dockerfiles: one for each application. Each dockerfile is a multistage build. Can you work with this or do you want an example? I would have to write an answer for it then.

Comment: My idea was to create a multi stage build, but the problem is the context that i'm trying to define on my docker-compose.yml (the projects are in separate folders and i have difficult to create this configuration). If you can provide an example (Dockerfile and docker-compose) would be apreciate for other users too :))

Comment: Can you at least share the folder structure?

Comment: I updated the question with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proposed solution with multi-stage builds.

To replicate your setup I created this structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile-app1
├── application1
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── resources
│           └── webapp
│               ├── WEB-INF
│               │   └── web.xml
│               └── index.jsp
├── core
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── com
│       │           └── test
│       │               └── App.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── test
│                       └── AppTest.java
```

In the pom.xml file from Application 1 I added the dependency to `core`:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I named the Dockerfile `Dockerfile-app1`, this way you can have more than 1 of them.

This is the Dockerfile-app1:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8 as build

WORKDIR /apps

COPY ./core .
RUN mvn clean install

FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8

# If you comment this out then the build fails because it cannot find the dependency to 'core'
COPY --from=build /root/.m2 /root/.m2

COPY ./application1 ./

RUN mvn clean install
```

You should probably add an entrypoint at the end to run your project or even better add another 3rd stage that only copies the generated artefacts and runs your project (this way the final image will not have your sourced in).

The first stage only builds the `core` submodule.

The second stage used the results of the first stage, copies only the source for application1 and builds it.

You can easily replicate this for `application2` by creating a similar file `Dockerfile-app2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yesterday after some experiments i replicated this structure, and it works. Mhhh you think is possible to have Dockerfile-app1 in a folder? A folder that contains Dockerfile-app1 and docker-compose.yml. Thats because if i leave Dockerfile-app1 alone i need to create a git repo with all the projects togheter. Would be wonderful to have a folder myapp-docker that do the trick.. is possible ?

Comment: I believe each application should have its own Dockerfile (next to the pom.xml). The same for the core project. Then you can build the core project once and push that image to a registry (if you want) and use that image as a base for each of your applications. So a Dockerfile for an application would start with `FROM core:latest`. Wouldn't this work better for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using maven, try [dockerfile-maven](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) to build the image. You don't want any of your build information inside of your image (like what the dependencies are), you should just add the jar at the end. I usually use it together with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and `repackage`, to get a fully self-contained jar.